# How do I use Interactive Magento Console

Tags: magento

I have downloaded IMC and don't know how to use it. I am using Denver it is the same like wamp, xamp and so on. I was reading developer book of Magento And there are following notes that describes how to connect to magento folder.

Please help me how can I do it if I use on my local computer `Wamp|Xamp|Denver`!?

=========================Developer book==========================================

For this purpose, I have created the Interactive Magento Console (IMC), which is
a shell script specially created for this book and inspired by Ruby's own Interactive Ruby Console (IRB). Follow these steps:

1. The first thing we will need to do is to install the IMC. To do so, download
   the source files from https://github.com/amacgregor/mdg_imc and
   extract them under your Magento test installation. The IMC is a simple
   Magento shell script that will allow us to test our code in real time.
2. Once you extracted the script, log in to the shell of your virtualbox.
3. Next, we will need to navigate to our Magento root folder. If you are using
   the default vagrant box, the installation is already provided; the root folder
   is located under `/srv/www/ce1720/public_html/`, and we navigate to it by
   running the following command line:
   `$ cd /srv/www/ce1720/public_html`
4. Finally, we can start the IMC by running the following command line:
   `$ php shell/imc.php`
5. If everything is installed successfully, we should see a new line starting with

## magento >.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually the original author of that script. The readline functions are not available on Windows, which the version of the script that was "borrowed" relies upon. I've since added some fallback support which uses `stream_get_line` to read `STDIN`. You can get the latest version here: https://github.com/rgranadino/Interactive-Magento-Console

This fallback support isn't as handy as using readline but it could still come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

After all of the preparation in this book, you should delete this code in shell/imc.php

```
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, array($this, 'sigintShutdown'));
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, array($this, 'sigintShutdown'));
```

And now, it works.